# MsTest does not Debug into a child project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest

I have a VS2017 solution with three projects:

Solution

- Project A
- Project B
- Project Test

So I have a test that calls a method in Project A.  This method has a call that goes into Project B.  When I debug the test I am able to step into Project A.  When it comes time to step into Project B the debugger just steps over and not into the project.

The project configuration for all three projects is set to Debug.  At this point I have been unable to see why I am not able to debug into Project B.

Comment: put a break point in the method being called in ProjectB and see if it breaks there when debugging.

Comment: Make sure project B is running or you have attached a process by going to Debug - Attach Process then attach to w3wp. If w3wp is not listed, open IIS and and browse to the site of project B.

Comment: Thanks.  I do have a break point in project B.  Project B is a straight forward dll and the project is included in the solution.

Comment: Hmm. Try to clean and rebuild project B

Comment: Yeah...I have done that as well.

Comment: hmm. Try setting a breakpoint on the constructor of the class in ProjectB.

Comment: That is an interesting idea.  It didn't work but now I am wondering if my Test is setting up the IoC container incorrectly.  I am going to look into that and see if that is why it is unable to  get to project b.

Comment: Are you using Ninject? I'm kind of new to that but I was having a similar problem because I didn't add bind statements to the NinjectWebCommon.cs file.

Answer (score 1):

So Rich got me on the right path.  The constructor of the class in Project B was not being hit.  To add further clarity Project A is a C# Web Api project.  When using Postman I am able to step into Project B.  This tells me that outside of a test I have my IoC set up correctly (The project is using  Castle Windsor DI).

This leads me to believe that I am not scaffolding my test correctly.  The company I am at is using Moq, so I will have to dive into that documentation to see what I am doing incorrectly.